# PHP echo stripping formatting in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, formatting

Using Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress, I have the following code:

```
if(the_sub_field('company_name')) { 

   echo '<strong>Company name:</strong>'; 
   echo '<p>' . the_sub_field('company_name') . '</p>';
}
```

When the page renders though, the company name renders (the_sub_field) but the **Company name:** does not.

This has also happened in a number of other places in my code when I echo some html out.

Is there a reason for this? Does it have to do with ACF? Many thanks

**EDIT:**
Even if I try it like this the *Company name:* is stripped compltely:

```
    <?php if(the_sub_field('company_name')) { ?>
        <strong>Company name:</strong>
        <p><?php the_sub_field('company_name') ?></p>;
    <?php } ?>
```

**EDIT:** 
Placing the Company Name: outside of the IF statement works, but I would like for it to be inside the IF statement as I want it to render out only if that statement is true of course.

```
<?php

    echo '<strong>Company name:</strong>'; 
    if(the_sub_field('company_name')) {
        echo '<p>' . the_sub_field('company_name') . '</p>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you guys are marking this On Hold...it is WordPress, Advanced Custom Fields and PHP related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `the_sub_field()` echoes the Subfield, so in your conditional the field `company_name` gets echoed.

However, this function does not return true, so the conditional is not met.

You need to use another `if` statement:

```
if ( get_sub_field('company_name') && get_sub_field('company_name') != '' ) {

    // echo it

}
```